# Helmholtz Equation Exterior of a Sphere with Dirichlet Boundary Conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, laplacian

I tried to solve the Helmoltz Equation $\Delta \psi=\lambda\psi$ on the exterior of a sphere of radius $R$ in 3 dimensions with Dirichlet b.c.. I know that in the $\lambda=0$ case the problem is solved by
$$\psi(x, y)=\frac{1}{4\pi|y-x|}-\frac{1}{4\pi\frac{|x|}{R}|y-x^{*}|},$$

where $x^{*}=\frac{R^{2}x}{|x|^{2}}$ is the Kelvin transform of the point $x$ ($x$, $y\in\mathbb{R}^3$).
Does the same procedure holds to solve the general $\lambda$ case? And so is

$$\psi(x, y)=\frac{e^{-\sqrt{\lambda}|y-x|}}{4\pi|y-x|}-\frac{e^{-\sqrt{\lambda}\frac{|x|}{R}|y-x^{*}|}}{4\pi\frac{|x|}{R}|y-x^{*}|}$$
the solution for $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Do you mean $z$ to be the vertical coordinate? In that case, this is not the Helmholtz equation... The Helmholtz equation is $$(\Delta+k^2)u=0$$
Where it is very important that $k$ is **constant**.

Comment: Nope z is a (a priori complex) number. Maybe i can change it to lambda to avoid confusion.

Comment: If you want to solve the equation with spherical boundary conditions, switching to spherical coordinates will definitely help.

Comment: See the "three dimensional solutions" part of the following: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_equation

Comment: Ok, I thought about spherical armonics. But at least in the $\lambda=0$ case, is the solution I reported here correct?

Comment: In the $\lambda=0$ case it reduces to Laplace's equation. Your solution does not look like the usual one. What makes it rather odd is that you claim to be solving the equation in three spacial dimensions, but your function takes two arguments. Please clarify this.

Comment: The harmonic sphere solution works also for  complex numbers right?

Comment: Sure, there is nothing stopping it from working. You will just get a complex valued solution. But yours doesn't look like what I'd expect.

Comment: $x,y$ are in$\mathbb{R^3}$ as I written. I put the charge in the position $x$ instead that in the origin, and used the image method to find the right correction function for the dirichlet b.c. This method works in the halfplane also for $\lambda\ne 0$, I am.not sure if it works on the sphere for $\lambda\ne 0$>\.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130706/discussion-between-k-defaoite-and-spuriousmatemagician).

Comment: Ok I think i misexplained what i am searching for. I am searching for the green function for the Helmholtz operator in the exterior of a sphere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically, we would like to solve the BVP
$$(\nabla^2+k^2)u=0\\u(\boldsymbol r)=0~~\text{when}~~|\boldsymbol r|=R$$
The $k^2$ is a matter of convenience. If $\lambda$ in your equation is actually a positive real number, we can take $k$ to be purely imaginary. Keep in mind that the equation is not fully determined, since this is a second order equation for which we have only supplied one boundary condition.

I've taken the position of the charged particle to be at the origin. We can just use a coordinate shift later to be able to put the charged object at any position we want. Based on how I'm interpreting your question, I think we can go ahead and assume that $u$ has some nice symmetry, i.e, the angular dependence vanishes, $\partial_\theta u=\partial_\phi u=0$. In that case, the Laplacian takes the form
$$\nabla^2u=\frac{1}{r^2}\left(r^2\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}\right)=\frac{2}{r}\partial_ru+\partial_r^2u$$
So now instead of a PDE, we actually have an ODE
$$u''(r)+\frac{2}{r}u'(r)+k^2u(r)=0$$
So... how to solve this? Well, *out of the blue*, we can try an ansatz
$$u(r)=v(r)/r$$
If you plug this in for $u$ and go through the calculations, you will find that it simplifies to
$$\frac{v''(r)+k^2v(r)}{r}=0$$
Assuming $r\neq 0$ we can multiply both sides and solve for $v$ to get
$$v(r)=c_1\sin(kr)+c_2\cos(kr)$$
And thus
$$u(r)=c_1\frac{\sin(kr)}{r}+c_2\frac{\cos(kr)}{r}$$
Our boundary condition reads
$$c_1\sin(kR)+c_2\cos(kR)=0\implies c_2=-c_1\tan(kR)$$
Hence
$$u(r)=c_1\left(\frac{\sin(kr)}{r}-\tan(kR)\frac{\cos(kr)}{r}\right)$$
We can now shift this equation by some vector $\boldsymbol{r}_0$, to get
$$u(\boldsymbol{r})=c_1\left(\frac{\sin(k|\boldsymbol{r}-\boldsymbol{r}_0|)}{|\boldsymbol{r}-\boldsymbol{r}_0|}-\tan(kR)\frac{\cos(k|\boldsymbol{r}-\boldsymbol{r}_0|)}{|\boldsymbol{r}-\boldsymbol{r}_0|}\right)$$
Maybe this helps?